# Wordpress website links redirect to homepage

Tags: wp-query

[image]I have created a wordpress.com website and have added a navigation that links my pages and external links. The external links are working fine but all in-site links to other pages re-direct me to the homepage for some reason.

Cheveninghub.co.uk is the website.

Thanks for any input in advance.

Comment: This stack is for WP developers using self-hosted WordPress installations. You should seek support through the [WordPress.com support](https://wordpress.com/support/) channels.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Admin, Settings, Permalinks, and change whatever is there to another choice. Save the setting. Then go back and change it to what you want it to be. Save the setting. Then try going to a page on your site.

Also, check that your htaccess file has the basic WordPress settings. See here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/

Comment: Hi Rick. Thanks for the reply. I don't seem to have a permalink menu or tab in my wordpress settings. I have added an image in the original post indicating this.

Comment: Because you are using wordpress.com, instead of self-hosting WordPress. See the comment to your question. You need to ask this on the wordpress.com site, not here in the Stack for WordPress.